# How to pass options to package required by class loaded with \LoadClass?

Tags: documentclass-writing

I am writing a .cls file, where I have a `\LoadClass{FooClass}` command. Now `FooClass` loads a package, say `BarPackage` to which I need to pass the option `SomeOption`. I have tried the following:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MyNewClass}[2018/03/11 Some Comment]

\PassOptionsToPackage{SomeOption}{BarPackage}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[other, options]{FooClass}  % FooClass.cls contains
                                      % \RequirePackage{BarPackage}
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick. Although `BarPackage` is loaded, it does not act as if `SomeOption` was passed.

I need to be able to keep whatever options `FooClass` already loads `BarPackage` with, but add `SomeOption` to them.

Comment: `\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{FooClass}}`?

Comment: You could try `\LoadClassWithOptions` to pass any undeclared options to `FooClass`.

Comment: I am not trying to pass options to `FooClass`. I am trying to add options to the ones that `BarPackage` is already loaded with by `FooClass`.

Comment: You should pass unrecognised options on from a parasitic class to its host class anyway, I think. Besides, packages automatically get access to options passed to the class, so you don't need to do anything additional. You don't say, but I assume you didn't actually try either of the suggestions made above.